# QtWebSockets chat client

Tags: c++, qt, websocket

Has anyone implemented a client with subprotocol "chat" using QtWebSockets? I have attempted to modify the existing examples to do so but can't seem to modify the protocol. I fail every handshake attempt to websocket servers that I can easily connect to with javascript. Thus, I know the handshake I need to use, but can't figure out how to modify the one used in QtWebSocket.

I've built all the examples and the echo client works. How do I modify the echo client example for connecting to a server with chat protocol?

Comment: Have you more information regarding the chat protocol you are referring to? AFAIK, the subprotocols are not standardised, so it depends on the service you are trying to contact. QtWebSockets contains a sample chat client and server, but that doesn't use a dedicated protocol.

Comment: I don't see a sample chat client in QtWebSocket - just a server, to which a standard html/javascript-based client can connect. I am not sure how to begin modifying the QtWebSocket "echo client" example so that it uses a different version, V_12, of the websocket protocol, and any other customized handshake values.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were referring to this: https://qt.gitorious.org/qtplayground/websockets. This is an add-on module hosted on the playground of Qt itself.

Comment: I am indeed referring to that module. I can't find any documentation o address the "handshake issues" that results from my attempt to connect to a "JWebSocket" server when using the QtWebSockets clients.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that JWebSocketServer does not support V13, which is the standard Web Socket protocol (other versions are all draft specifications). If I was you, I wouldn't bother with that server and look for another one.

Comment: By the way, I checked JWebSocket and it claims to support V13.

Comment: @Kurt Your advice was sound. I compiled another server and everything now works great. Thanks again for your help!